# Why get request works fine in Postman but not locally?

Tags: angular, get, http-headers, postman

Postman gives me proper response, but when in browser I get 401 Unauthorized. Why?

This is my Service

```
  getDepartments(id): Observable<any>{
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/api/v1/universities/' + id + '/departments/', {headers: 
  this.httpHeaders} )
  }
```

This is my component.ts

```
  getAllDepartments = () =>{
this.api.getDepartments(this.token.university).subscribe(
  data =>{
    this.departments = data;
    
  },
  error => {
      console.log(error);
  }
)
```

}

These are how I create my headers:

```
httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type':'application/json'});
```

That's what I get:

```
Accept: application/json
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7
Authorization: Bearer 4fa4071036d107c482d2f768921518034cb9ae13
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
Host: signmeupapi.herokuapp.com
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/admin
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: cross-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.88 Safari/537.36 OPR/73.0.3856.284 
(Edition Campaign 76)
```

Link is fine, I have the same token in headers and I'm totally lost. On the server side cors headers work fine, I was able to log in and get token, but here nothing seems to work.

Comment: in Angular 2+ `HttpHeaders` are immutable. Can you show how you build the headers (`this.httpHeaders`)? Did you check what's inside the header? Put a `debugger;` tag in front of that call, open up your dev console, and have a look at what's inside there;

Comment: I edited post with headers info. Could you explain where exacly I should put `debbuger`?

Comment: ```getDepartments(id): Observable<any>{ debugger;
  return this.http.get(this.baseurl + '/api/v1/universities/' + id + '/departments/', {headers: 
  this.httpHeaders} )
  }``` 


And isnt `this.httpHeaders` missing the `Authorization` header?

Comment: I just found that the problem was not in Angular, but my backend. Some modules had wrong permissions. But thank you for your help!